# Way to shorten jquerycode

Tags: jquery

I have several modal popup windows which all use the same settings. One of these requires the following code.

```
var $modal = $('#modal')
  .attr('id', 'modal')
  .css({zIndex: 3000});

$('#modal-trigger').click(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault(), $('#modal').css("visibility","visible");

  $(this).overlay({
    effect: 'fade',
    glossy: true,
    opacity: 0.8,
    closeOnClick: true,
    onShow: function() {
      $('body').append($modal);
    },
    onHide: function() {
      $modal.remove();
    },
  })
});
```

So making a second one means changing the *modal* to something else in the following places:

var $modal = $('#**modal**')

.attr('id', '**modal**')

$('**#modal-trigger**').click(function(evt) {

$('body').append(**$modal**);

**$modal**.remove();

Is there a way to shorten this, so I do not have to keep adding the full code to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1):

Write a jQuery plugin. It's easy. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

That said, it looks like you'd probably be reimplementing something like [jQuery blockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/).

---

BTW, there is no reason to select an element by ID and immediately set its ID attribute as this line of code does:

```
$('#modal').attr('id', 'modal')
```

Answer (score 1):

I would propose:

- caching elements (using variables you created),
- using function within callback (passing "context" and the element to be influenced when clicking the trigger,
- not assigning something that has been assigned (by `#modal` you are selecting something that already has `id="modal"`,

It would look like that (it has not been tested however):

```
var $modal1 = $('#modal1').css({zIndex: 3000});
var $modal2 = $('#modal2').css({zIndex: 3000});

var doStuff = function(context, element){
  element.css("visibility","visible");
  context.overlay({
    effect: 'fade',
    glossy: true,
    opacity: 0.8,
    closeOnClick: true,
    onShow: function() {
      $('body').append(element);
    },
    onHide: function() {
      element.remove();
    },
  })
}

$('#modal1-trigger').click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    doStuff($(this), $modal1);
});

$('#modal2-trigger').click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    doStuff($(this), $modal2);
});
```

Please let me know if you find any errors there.

Comment: eh... one problem. after closing the overlay I cant reopen it. it only shows the overlay, not the modal

Comment: @Aeonius: I believe this was the original issue with your code, because you are using [`.remove()` function](http://api.jquery.com/remove/). You can solve it eg. by following the way similar to the example within [`.detach()` function documentation](http://api.jquery.com/detach/).

Comment: so replacing .remove with .detach? or am i looking at this too simple?

Comment: @Aeonius: I think `element = element.detach();` instead of `element.remove();` should do the trick, but you should test it.

Comment: this does not remove the modal window. the overlay goes away, but the modal stays visible. sorry for being a noob. thank you for your help!

Comment: @Aeonius: I am not sure, what you are trying to achieve. I can not help you.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a function? I think this should work:

```
function doStuff(id)
{
    var $modal = $('#' + id)
  .attr('id', id)
  .css({zIndex: 3000});

$('#' + id + '-trigger').click(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault(), $('#' + id).css("visibility","visible");

  $(this).overlay({
    effect: 'fade',
    glossy: true,
    opacity: 0.8,
    closeOnClick: true,
    onShow: function() {
      $('body').append($modal);
    },
    onHide: function() {
      $modal.remove();
    },
  })
});
}
```

Comment: how do I call the function? the link to open the modal before was <a id="modal-trigger2" class="resizeme" href="#">open2</a>